# Rav Scheinberg and Tzitzis (series of questions)

Tags: tzitzis, minhag, blessing, rabbis

I have heard that Rav Scheinberg wore many garments with ציציות on them at a time. . .

Is this true?

If so, why did he do it?

If not, why do other people do it?

How many ברכות do they make when putting them on?

If the answer is >1, at what point in the putting on process is the 2nd ברכה made?

Comment: As YDK noted in his answer, it's R' Scheinberg who's known for doing this, not R' Elyashiv (shlit"a for both of them).

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question (for some reason) to reflect this fact.

Comment: Rav Scheinberg recently passed away, so I have edited the question to past tense.  Still a question worth discussing.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/changing-shlitas-to-zals

Comment: He wore 180 pairs http://www.learntorah.com/lt-shiur-details.aspx?id=7348

Answer (score 7):

Regarding Rav Scheinberg's daughter who was once ill,he did not take on extra tzitzis, that is only why he doesn't speak on Shabbos. He has not publicized the reason for his wearing multiple pairs of tzitzis, though he has stated that every pair is a mitzvah. He makes one bracha, if any, since the talis gadol can patur the bracha on tzitzis. He dons bundles of 18 at at time.

Comment: ARTI, welcome to mi.yodeya and thank you for this informative answer! To reap all of the benefits that come with full mi.yodeya membership, consider clicking "Register" at the top of your page. We look forward to seeing you around in the future.

Comment: I heard my version from one of R' Scheinbergs grandkids.  I didn't know that he doesn't talk on Shabbos, although I do know from an eyewitness that (must be back in the 50's) R' Scheinbergs wife took him to a din Torah by R' Moshe because R' Scheinberg would only speak Lashon Kodesh on Shabbos Kodesh, Which the rebbitzen did not know at least at that time.  (R' Moshe ruled for the rebbitzen)

Comment: ARTI, where did you hear your version?

Answer (score 4):

Rav Sheinberg originally put on 18 as a neder if his daughter recovered from an illness many years ago.  He has added more since.

I assume he only makes 1 bracha just like "we" only make 1 on both our talis gadol and katan.

Comment: For those curious, here is a video:
http://www.mahnishmah.com/system/scripts/modules/admin/pages/show_page.cgi?p=13926

Comment: This is a better link to the video: http://youtu.be/q9W17CEn7vY

Answer (score 0):

I was told that he wore multiple tzitzis garments to be *yotzei* all the *shittos* (e.g. Yemenite-Rambam tying, Sephardic tying, etc.), but this doesn't make much sense to me since I figure 5 or 10 or 20 should be plenty.

Comment: Beyond the two knots and 3 rings, Tzitzit tying is a custom and nothing more: nobody claims that their custom is more halachically acceptable than other minhagim, or that one shita is yotze while another is not.

Comment: @l' The RAMBAM and the ARiZal disagree.

Comment: @mochinrechavim Are you saying that the Rambam and Ari disagree with l ' 's statement, or that the two of them disagree about how to tie and there disagreement is such that it's existence argues on l ' 's statement?

Comment: @DoubleAA The RAMBAM and the ARiZal would disagree with the difference of opinion is "nothing more than a custom". V'Dal.

Comment: @mochinrechavim Can you source that? You're saying the rambam would think ari tzitzit are pasul, and vice versa?

Comment: @DoubleAA Above is a statement that tying tzitzis is just a custom and NOTHING MORE. I said that the Arizal and the Rambam would disagree. See Hilchos Tzitzis in Mishneh Torah and Hilchos Tzitzis in Alter Rebbe Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @mochinrechavim I have read the rambam there. What makes you say there is some obligation to do it a certain way either mideoraita or miderabanan?

Comment: @DoubleAA I never said that the tying was either d'orisa or d'rabanan. I was simply saying that the RAMBAM and ARiZal would disagree with the above statement that tying is a custom and "NOTHING MORE". There is a brazenness to the attitude of how individuals here typing that almost seems to mock the Torah. It also would also seem to insult the intelligence of one of the pillars of Lithuanian Jewry by implying that he wore those additional pairs for no reason.

Comment: @mochinrechavim You are ridiculous. Vram only pointed out why Ben's reason could not be the reason that R Scheinberg put on multiple pairs. That doesn't make R Scheinberg the idiot here; only you for insulting Vram publicly. It's individuals like you who don't understand the difference between minhag and din that really make the Torah seem laughable.

Comment: Courtesy ping @l ' Vram

Comment: @DoubleAA You seem to be on point then. Thanks for putting me in my place. I will go back to learning the difference between minhag and halacha. While I am there I will figure out what the point was for anyone after RAMBAM to try to figure out how to tie tzitzis in the first place. I gave you a plus one for reminding my how completely pointless the internet is when trying to learn or teach the Emes of the Torah. Shkoaych. Im done.

Comment: @mochinrechavim Both the internet and the real world will be better off when those who call others brazen for bringing up valid halachik points are all done trying to teach the "Emes" of Torah. But you're more then welcome to stick around to try and learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Moreinu HaGaon HaRav HaTzaddik Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg, zatzal, did not (contrary to public belief) wear multiple sets of tzitzis due to a desire to be yotzi according to all views. All of his tzitzis were the same.

He did this because (1) each beged is a mitzvah, each second that one wears it and (2) b/c there are non-religious folks who don't do the mitzvah, so he wanted to "make up" for them.

There was a time when he wore almost 300 sets of tzitzis. He had skin problems because of this because it is very hot in Israel and his apartment (at one point) had no AC.

Source: A Gadol in Our Midst