# Wearing Two Tzizits

Tags: tzitzis

Would wearing two tzizits get you any extra mitzvah? Would you get the extra mitzvah by wearing two Talit katans or one talit gadol and one Talit khatan? Please cite sources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rav Scheinberg and Tzitzis (series of questions)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/rav-scheinberg-and-tzitzis-series-of-questions)

Comment: No Mitzva at all. A Bittul Aseh actually. See Menachot 3:7 ארבע ציצייות מעכבות זו את זו, שארבעתן מצוה אחת

Comment: Is the op referring to two pairs? I don’t follow @DoubleAA

Answer (score 4):

[Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) writes in his commentary to Numbers 15:39 that it is not proper to wear two garments with *tzitzit* at the same time. He derives this from two different phraseologies. First, the Torah says וראיתם אותו — "and you should see it". Ralbag argues that "it" means that there should be only one of them. The Torah also says  אשר תכסה בה — "that you cover with it". Again, Ralbag argues that "it" means that there should be only one:

> ועוד למדנו ממה שאמר וראיתם אתו ולא אותו וחברו ר"ל אין ראוי לאדם שישא יחד שני טליתות מצויינים וכן למדנו זה ממה שאמר אשר תכסה בה [ר"ל אחת ולא שתים

In his commentary to Deuteronomy 22:12 he goes further and states that wearing multiple garments with *tzitzit* leads to a belief in the lack of unity of God, and is a violation of *bal tosif* (adding to the commandments):

> ואחשוב שאין ראוי לאדם שילבש יחד שני בגדים שיש בהם ציצית שהרי נאמר אשר תכסה בה ולא בה ובחברתה וראיתם אתו ולא אותו וחבירו עם שזה יביא להאמנת השניות בשם יתעלה ובתורה כי זאת המצוה מעידה על הפך זה כמו שבארנו במה שקדם בסוף פרשת שלח לך ובכלל הנה כמו שיעברו על נשיאת שני תפילין בראש משום בל תוסיף מפני שיש מקום בראש ראוי להניח בו שני תפילין כן יעברו על נשיאת יותר מבגד ציצית אחד משום בל תוסיף שהרי האדם ראוי לעשות כמה בגדי ציצית כי לא הונח לו מקום מוגבל אם יהיה בבגד העליון או התחתון או האמצעי ואולם שאר הדינים אשר בציצית כבר בארנום בסוף פרשת שלח לך

R. Avigdor Tzorfati similarly writes that if someone has more than one garment with four corners, only one of them requires *tzitzit*, as the Torah's statement על ארבע כנפות כסותך — "on the four corners of your garment" implies specifically one garment:

**Pesak 275**

> וסבירא ליה לרבנו דאם היו לו לאדם כמה מיני ד' כנפות שאין צריך להטיל ציצית רק באחד מהם שנאמר על ארבע כנפות כסותך משמע לחד ולא לשנים

[R. Aharon ben Yaakov Hakohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_ben_Jacob_ha-Kohen) writes that there is a dispute whether or not multiple garments require tzitzit, and he says that neither side adduced proof:

> והיכא דלביש תרי מלבושים או שלש בעלי ארבע כנפות או יותר בזה יש מחלוקת בין הפוסקים יש אומרים שצריך להטיל ציצית בכלן ויש אומרים שאין צריך אלא בעליון ואין אחד מהם מביא ראיה לדבריו אלא משיקול הדעת

Notably, [R. Yosef Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo) completely rejects the view that only one garment would require *tzitzit*:

**[Beit Yosef Siman 8](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x23)**

> ה דבר פשוט בעיני ובארחות חיים מצאתי שיש אומרים שאין צריך להטיל אלא בעליון עד כאן ואני אומר דסברא דחויה היא זו ולית דחש לה

Comment: Is the ralbag arguing that one should only wear one four corned garment so only that garment is obligated in tzittzis bc it would be wrong to obligate oneself to wear tzittzis on mutliple garments it that regardless of how many four corned pieces of clothing one wears the tzitzis should only go on one of them?

Comment: @Dude Unlike the other sources mentioned, he doesn't discuss whether additional garments would be obligated, so he might mean the first option. Though it would be somewhat odd to both be obligated to do something and also violate bal tosif for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Any four-cornered garment made of wool or linen is obligated in tzitzit from the Torah, while other materials are obligated only Rabbinically(Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 9:1 and 10:1).

Therefore, wearing multiple four-cornered garments with tzitzit is counted as multiple mitzvot. This was also the practice of R' Chaim Pinchas Sheinberg ztz"l who wore upwards of 100 talitot katan with different shitot of tying their knots.

The issur of bal tosif applies *only* when one adds a fifth or more set of tzitzit to a four-cornered garment(as opposed to the four required by the Torah).

Wearing a a four-cornered garment lacking all four tzitziot is a bitul aseh and it is forbidden to wear such a garment until four tzitziot are placed on it, according to halacha and tradition of knotting them(SA OC 8:17).

A garment with more than four corners is also obligated in tzitzit. In this case, the tzitziot should be tied to the farthest of the five(or more) corners(SA OC 10:1).

Four cornered cloths(not clothing) are not obligated in tzitzit when they are meant for something other than clothing. Blankets, towels, scarves, and handkerchiefs are some examples(see SA OC 10:10-12).

Comment: Some of your claims are debatable and/or subject to Machloket