# Is one garment with Tzitzit strings the max, or may one wear more?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

I have searched Mi Yodeya and see a few questions on this topic but I do not feel as if this basic one has been answered. I am curious if it is halachically permissible to wear 2, or 3, etc. garments, each one with Tzitzit strings.

I want to explain why I think the other questions here are not duplicates.

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/115028/should-we-wear-multiple-pairs-of-tzitzit) discusses whether one *should* wear multiple. I am curious if it's allowed. Further, the answer there discusses whether or not it is proper but does not say whether it is assur.

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97634/wearing-two-tzizits/97637) seems to refer to the Heavenly reward conveyed for two pairs, and [the comment by DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97634/wearing-two-tzizits/97637#comment324533_97634) seems to say that is *is* assur to do. However, I am unclear on whether he is referring to more than 4 strings, or more than 1 garment.

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/rav-scheinberg-and-tzitzis-series-of-questions), the question is about Rav Scheinberg Zecher Tzaddik L'bracha, with [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82049/27916) saying that as per "A Gadol in Our Midst" each one is a mitzvah.

So, while there are three questions on this sitre that seem to pertain to this idea, I am seeing different ideas on whether it is muttar or assur to do, based on those comments and answers. My question, which I think is diofferent from those, or at least has not been answered in those, is whether anyone has asked a Halachic authority, or they have seen a Teshuva or Psak, that wearing multiple garments with Tzitzit strings, al pi halacha, is okay to do.

Comment: My comment says wearing two tzitzit [instead of the mandatory four] doesn't fulfill the mitzva. It doesn't address multiple garments.

Comment: I understand. It seemed to me the question was on garments. If it was to be understood the way you read it, I do not see why it would be an 'extra mitzvah'. Therefore, I understood it as two garments.

Answer (score 4):

It says expressly in [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 8:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.8.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that one can:

> **אם יש לו כמה בגדים של ארבע כנפות כלם חייבים בציצית** ואם לבשם כלם בלא הפסק והיה דעתו מתחלה על כלם לא יברך אלא ברכה אחת ואם מפסיק ביניהם צריך לברך על כל אחת ואחת וה"ה אם לא היה בדעתו מתחלה על כלם הוי כמפסיק ביניהם: הגה וכן אם פשט הראשון קודם שלבש השני צריך לחזור ולברך (ת"ה סי' מ"ה)
>
> **If one has many four cornered garments, all of them are obligated to have tzitzis.** And if one puts them all on without a break, and has in mind from the beginning about all of them, he only makes a single blessing. And if he does make an interruption between them, he needs to make a blessing on each one of them. And this is the law if he didn't have in mind from the beginning about all of them, that it's as if an interruption was made between them. Gloss: And so too if he removed the first [garment] before putting on the second [garment], he needs to return and make [another] blessing (T"H siman 45). (Sefaria translation)

The implication from the SA is that whilst one makes a single bracha when wearing multiple sets, it is okay to wear more than one set.

Comment: This is the generally accepted halacha, though as noted in the linked questions, it is the subject of a dispute in the rishonim.